# Best practice to add a Test-Button in a Orchard-AdminView

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I'd like to add a "Test"-Button to the Create/Edit-AdminViews in my Orchard-Module.
The Button itself is rendered fine using an additional shape.
Question: how can I make the button's action point to a "Test"-Action which gets the current ViewModel, performs the "Test", displays an info and returns the user to the view (passing the ViewModel back in again). 
At the Moment, it completely ignores it's surrounding Form.
Maybe there's already some working example and I simply couldn't find it?

Thanks for any help.
Sascha

PS: Code in Content.TestButton.cshtml

```
@using ( Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost(Url.Action("Test", new { controller = "DnsCheckAdmin" }), FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "col-md-5" }) )
{
    <fieldset class="test-button">
        <button type="submit" name="submit.Test" value="submit.Test">@T("Test settings")</button>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: In the html, is this form inside another form?

Comment: How does your controller look like?